# Resistor at the oscillator output

Tags: noise, oscillator

Why do some designs put a resistor in series at the oscillator output? does work like a dampening component to noise or is there a different purpose for it?

Can a chip ferrite be places instead of the resistor?

This is an example of a circuit:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The can be thought in many ways, from different points of view. What is important to remember that even if the oscillator is only 2 MHz, it will generate edges at 4 MHz and ideal edges have in theory frequencies up to infinity. The 7ns edge slew rate means  the bandwidth of the edge is past 100 MHz.

It can be a source termination for impedance matching a CMOS output to
PCB transmission line impedance. It may help to dissipate reflections from the unterminated MCU input as well.

It can be the R of an RC filter where the C is trace and input capacitance. It slows down the signal edges and removes high frequencies.

It can be thought as a current limiting resistor for driving the trace and input capacitance.

Anyway, it will make it easier for the oscillator output driver to drive capacitive loads and during transitions the required current is less that without.

It will help with EMC compliance and makes less noise on the oscillator supply voltage as lower gulps of current is needed each edge.

So in the end it removes ringing and under/overshoot from the clock edges that can cause problems in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

> *Why do some designs put a resistor in series at the oscillator output?*

It's only a [2 MHz oscillator module](https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ECS-2520MVLC.pdf) and, it's powered from the same rails as the chip on the left so, I don't expect that the resistor's presence is something that is needed to make the circuit work.

I suspect that the resistor is placed so that if the oscillator module needed to be bypassed with a directly injected clock, the resistor would facilitate that temporary connection. Of course, it could be that the unknown chip on the left may be able to generate its own clock internally and so the resistor might be useful here.

If the oscillator module were several tens of MHz and there was some distance between it and the chip on the left, the output resistor would be useful as a series termination (see transmission line theory and series terminated voltage sources).

> *Can a chip ferrite be places instead of the resistor?*

I expect that it could although I don't see an obvious reason to do so. The devil is in the detail so, if you have something in mind, it might be worth revealing your thoughts.

Comment: The image provided is not the actual circuit I have, I am using a 24MHz oscillator which is used for SerDes, in EMC RE tests I am seeing the 24MHz harmonics that are failing the testing which is why I thought of using a filter at the output instead.

Comment: @Shannon I suspect that the root cause of the EMC fail is in the serdes transmission itself; it will be at a significantly faster rate than 24 MHz (and harmonically related) and, it will probably be carried over a much longer distance than oscillator module to chip. That's my best guess.